# Как скачать всё, что находится в div?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

**ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ:** WebDriver, С#

**ИМЕЕТСЯ:**
Страница содержит

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="adDisplay extra-padding">
        <div class="container" id="1454894148_ima" style="width:728px;height:90px;">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.site.com/pagead/aclk?
                …
            </a>
        </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Между  `<div class="controls">`  и `<a target="_blank">`  количество `<div>` постоянно меняется

**ВОПРОС**
    1. Как добраться до `<a target="_blank" >`, чтобы потом извлечь из `href` ссылку?

или

2. Как скопировать всё что находится в `<div class="controls">`, чтобы потом извлечь ссылку из `<a target="_blank" >`?

Comment: а конструкции a target="_blank" href= с ненужной ссылкой может быть на сайте? Если нет, можно простейшим образом через indexOf взять или по regex признаку.

Answer (score 1):

```
string href = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".controls a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

если обязательно один из детей/ пра-детей/ пра-пра-пра-пра-детей (пропустить любоей количество детей в иерархии, главное что бы конечным нащадком был "а")

```
string href = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='container']//a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

если прямой

```
string href = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='container']/a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

если пропустить 1го нащадка любого типа, главное что бы следующим в иерархии был "а"

```
string href = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='container']/*/a")).GetAttribute("href");
```